# NGINX routing address with location on two different apps running on localhost

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt, nginx-location

I am running multiple flask apps on ubuntu server each having different ports (e.g. 8003,1642)
This is my configuration file

```
    server {
      server_name api.example.org
      if ($scheme != "https"){
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
      }
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8003;
      }
  location /dev {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1642;
      }
}
```

This is configuration file for setting up ssl using let's encrypt NGINX, however `sudo nginx -t` shows the format is correct and generates ssl successfully, but when i try to access only port 8003 (address with '/') is accessible and not the second one,
How can i configure this so that i can access both ports using url end points?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Are you requesting `https://api.example.org:8003`? It’s not clear what you mean with `when i try to access only port 8003 is accessible and not the second one` What error does ‘the second one’ give? Please edit the question to clarify exactly what you are doing and expecting.

Comment: Btw `if ($scheme != "https"){` it’s considered better to use two explicit server declarations, one listening for http traffic and the other https, rather than to do if checks like this

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i am quite new to this so still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : The problems seems to be hosted address on gunicorn, when the apps were hosted on 0.0.0.0 nginx was not able to access using localhost, so i configured the output address to `127.0.0.1:8003` and `127.0.0.1:1642` then i can easily access different ports using same domain name with added routes ([www.example.com/api](http://www.example.com/api))